# How many laws of friction are conventionally used?

Tags: forces, friction, drag, dissipation

I was studying laws of friction. [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction#Laws_of_dry_friction) says there are three laws based on Coulomb's model of friction.

However, most of the other websites say there are five laws, stating

> 1. When an object is moving, the friction is proportional and perpendicular to the normal force.

> 2. Friction is independent of the area of contact so long as there is an area of contact.

> 3. The coefficient of static friction is slightly greater than the coefficient of kinetic friction.

> 4. Within rather large limits, kinetic friction is independent of velocity.

> 5. Friction depends upon the nature of the surfaces in contact.

I am confused which to choose. I mostly prefer Wikipedia for making my notes, however this is creating confusion.

I want to know, which ones do we choose and use conventionally?

(I myself feel that the three laws are better as they seem technical and not redundant.)

Comment: The 5 are simply more detailed

Comment: They are all correct.  But as always there are limits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not see them as law, I would rather call them properties of friction forces based on experimental facts. All the properties (Laws) you have given are true ( at certain approximation) for frictional forces.

Friction depends on detailed structure
at the molecular level and is generally too complicated to be analyzed
from basic principles. Consequently, friction must be treated phenomenologically,
described by empirical rules. The magnitude of the
force of friction varies in a complicated way with the nature of the surfaces
and their relative velocity. In fact, the only thing we can always
say about friction is that it opposes the motion that would occur in its
absence.

Comment: I know that all of them are correct (to a certain limit ofc). But I want to know which one should I use for preparing my notes? Which one are used conventionally/commonly?

Comment: You should go with wikipedia. Besides they are just properties , You can make a heading like Properties of friction force and write all of them.

Comment: That was what I was exactly wondering. Because the five laws seem much like the "atomic theory" and less like "laws of atomic combinations". (Sorry because I related to Chemistry!)

Comment: "Laws" in physics are codifications of observations. They don't represent eternal truths. Ohm's law, Young's law, Boyle's law, etc. are all things that capture patterns seen in particular circumstances.